# How do you form questions with чи?

Tags: граматика, non-native-speaker

I know you can make questions that are just declarative sentences with a question mark or intonation, like this: "Цей хлопчик хороший?"

But if you want to make a grammatically explicit question with Чи, what's the right way to do that? Does either (or both) of those work?

- Чи цей хлопчик хороший? Чи я його кохала? etc
- Чи хороший цей хлопчик? Чи кохала я його? etc

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The *чи* usually has two functions:

- as conjuction it can express *or*;
- as an adverbial form it introduces a yes-no question.

If we speak about second then it works as a simple question where you added *чи*.

Other [notes](http://sum.in.ua/s/chy). Just *чи* is usually used:

1. To enhance the interrogative nature of the sentence.
2. To make assumptions.

   Itʼs simillar to English where at the and of question: *(comma) [negative verb]?* And Ukrainian also has this construct: *(comma) чи не так?*
3. For rhetorical questions.

There is also a construction as *чи не* which used:

1. To make assumptions.

   Itʼs the same as with just *чи* but assumption is more notable.
2. As *like* as *similar to*, can be used with numbers too.

   For example mentioned early *чи не так?* but as an indepence question also may mean *like so?* where *так* isnʼt used as *yes* as previous.
3. For expressing the possibility, the [polite] desire for something.

   In the case of desiring it similar to *would [noun] [verb]*: *чи не xoчете? → would you like?*

---

You usally understand question from intonation and context what was asked. Otherwise an order of sentence can change your attention. For example I understand those questions in this way. About

1. *this good boy*

   Both questions can mean just *Is this boy good?* But because of order you may understand those question as:

   - *[Чи] цей хлопчик хороший? → Is it this boy [among others] who good? → То са́ме цей хлопчик, хто хороший?*
   - *[Чи] хороший цей хлопчик? → Is [exactly] this boy [really] good? → Цей хлопчик справді хороший?*

   Where *among others*, *exactly* or something like those appeared because of in regular speech *цей* is usually redundant. Therefore the second question also can represent your doubt which in some contexts [especially with intonation] can be taken rudely.
2. *I love him*

   Both questions can mean *Did I love him*? Again, but because of order you also can expect addition info like:

   - *[Чи] я його кохала? → Was it me who love him? → То я, хто кохала його?*
   - *[Чи] кохала я його? → Was it a feeling of love from me to him? → Та дія від мене до нього була коханням?*

   As you can notice, a first word or phrase can take your attention to itself.

Answer (score 4):

This particle is optional. According to the Academic Explanatory Dictionary of the Ukrainian Language (Академічний тлумачний словник української мови),

[Чи](http://sum.in.ua/s/chy) (particle), Section 2, interrogative sentences:

- Used to **enhance the interrogative nature** of the sentence. In this case, *чи* is optional as it only adds more emotional expressiveness to the sentence.
- Used for **rhetorical** questions. Subjectively, I find it merely close to English "isn't it?" and alike, except that the English one uses a negation while *чи* doesn't. See below for another use that involves the negation.

  > *Цей хлопчик розбив вікно. **Чи** хороший він?* — This boy broke a glass. Is he good (now)?

  Here the speaker assumes that the underlying clause **is untrue**.
- *Чи не*:

  1. used in meaning: *maybe*, expressing the **possibility** or the desire for something.
     I can't think of a good example (that would be essentially different from the next one), but generally it is for phrases like "shouldn't we...?" etc.
  2. used to express an assertion, making **assumptions**, a plausible guess.
     Here the speaker assumes that the underlying clause **is true**.

     > **Чи не** кохала я його? — **Didn't** I love him?

     or a direct English equivalent:

     > I loved him, **didn't I?**

     or another one:

     > **Чи не** твій брат цей хлопчик? — **Isn't** this boy your brother?
  3. = roughly, mostly

     > *Цей хлопчик вчиться **чи не на всі** оцінки «відмінно»* — This boy gets **mostly all** A*'s in his study.

Comment: Ой, ти раніше відповів і теж брав з СУМ-11-а. Ну, най буде.